# how to forbid recording of these errors?

Tags: nginx

how to forbid recording of these errors?

> 2021/02/18 22:34:24 [error] 14878#14878: *1566624 open() "/home/admin/web/public_html/xaos/16x16/sword.png" failed (2: No such file or directory),

Answer (score 0):

These errors can removed from the error log by using:

```
log_not_found off;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#log_not_found) for details.

Alternatively, the error message will not be generated if the 404 (not found) response is as a result of processing a `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.